# How to iterate through all combinations within a FOR loop?

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, combinations

I want to set up a loop where items in one array is subtracted from from elements in another array while minimising the leftovers.

**A simplified example**

Six rolls of three different lengths (10, 12, 15) are in one array ***roll_list***. The first row is the lengths and the second row is the corresponding quantities.

Ten different parts of lengths (7, 6, 6, 5, 4, 7, 5, 4, 6, 5) need to be made from the six available rolls.

The parts need to be produced in the order as shown in the array ***part_list***, but the rolls may be used in any order.

How can I set up a loop to iterate all the possible combination and find out the least amount of waste?
I have managed to do one possible iteration sequential to the ***roll_list*** array, but I am struggling to figure out how to attempt all possible combinations.

- One part cannot be made using more than one roll. So Part A cannot include material from Roll X and Y.
- Once a roll enters production, it needs to be used straight away. It cannot be removed from production and brought back to be reused.

Appreciate any suggestions.

```
roll_list = [10 12 15; 3 1 2];
roll_tot=sum(roll_list(1,:).*roll_list(2,:));
part_list = [7 6 6 5 4 7 5 4 6 5];
parts_total_length = sum(part_list);
b=1;
c=1;
waste=0;
for a = 1:length(part_list)
    if roll_list(1,b) >= part_list(a) && roll_list(2,c) >= 1
        roll_list(1,b) = roll_list(1,b) - part_list(a);
    else
        waste = waste + roll_list(1,b);
        roll_list(2,c) = roll_list(2,c)-1;
        roll_list(1,:) = [10 12 15];
        if roll_list(2,c) == 0
            b=b+1;
            c=c+1;
        end
        roll_list(1,b) = roll_list(1,b) - part_list(a);
    end
end
```

Comment: To get you started, `unique(perms(part_list), 'rows')` will give you a matrix where each row is one of the possible orderings of `part_list`. If you loop over the number of rows of that matrix then inside the loop you can try making the parts from each possible combination of rolls. Instead of the way you have formatted `roll_list` it might make more sense to have a 1-D list i.e. `[10 10 10 12 15 15]`, then you could get all the possible orderings of the rolls by the same method.

Comment: Note: I think this will run in a reasonable amount of time for the data in your example, but if you want it to work for more parts or rolls you might find the calculation time becomes unviable and you might need to look at some sort of optimised search rather than this brute force method.

Comment: @nekomatic I have managed to solve this particular problem using unique(perms(part_list), 'rows') but as you mentioned, it is not scalable. I need to explore how to split the problem into smaller chunks before solving it. Thanks for the response.